# Is there a way to call self-defined macro functions from within writer document?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'd like to call sub and function from libre office basic from document text, such as

```
[call sub initNumbering()]
text - blah
Some caption defined as "Card Nr."+[call function getCardNr()]
text - blah
[call sub nextCard()]
```

But I didn't find a way to accomplish calling those functions in such a way.

I tried in libre writer to use menu "Insert-Field-more fields", and there tab "functions" - it lists "execute macro", and I even can navigate to the self written macro, but after "insert" it only shows a thin grey placeholder instead of the contents the macro function should generate to be displayed as part of the text.

Maybe some small "hello world" example - first the macro definition:

```
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Function getName() as String
    getName = "Hello world!"
End Function
```

then the ODT using it, after inserting the function by menu "Insert-Field-more fields", tab "functions", "execute macro":

```
Generated text: „vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Test.getName?language=Basic&location=document“
```

I'd expect to have "Hello world" inserted between the quotes, but it shows only the link of the inserted execute-macro-field, not its result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/01/04090003.html:

> Execute Macro Inserts a text field that runs a macro when you click the field in the document. To assign a macro to the field, click the Macro button.

For example, create a field with reference text "Run GetName" assigned to the following subroutine:

```
Function GetName as String
    GetName = "Hello world!"
End Function

Sub ReplaceField
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oField As Object
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    For Each oField In oDoc.TextFields
        If oField.supportsService("com.sun.star.text.TextField.Macro") Then
            If oField.getPresentation(False) = "Run GetName" Then
                oField.Hint = GetName()
            End If
        End If
    Next oField
End Sub
```

[image: insert field to execute macro]

Click on the field, which will change its text to "Hello world!" instead of "Run GetName".

You could change the code to go to `oField.getAnchor()`, delete the field and replace it with whatever text content should go there.

Now, the initial part of your question is:

```
[call sub initNumbering()]
text - blah
Some caption defined as "Card Nr."+[call function getCardNr()]
text - blah
[call sub nextCard()]
```

To me, this looks like templating. So for example, instead of `[call sub initNumbering()]`, write `{{initNumbering}}` in that place. When all of your template fields are ready, run a macro that replaces all template fields with the content that should go in those fields.

Writer also has [a templates feature](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/swriter/guide/templates_styles.html) that does not require macros, so maybe that can do what you need. Or maybe a mail merge, with data for each card read from a database and inserted into the appropriate fields in the document.